# jQuery Dynamic Array with matching Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following data in my jQuery object:

> ### Group - Rank - Value
>
> A - 1 - 200
>   B - 2 - 200
>   C - 3 - 200
>   D - 3 - 500
>   E - 3 - 600
>   F - 3 - 400
>   G - 4 - 100
>   H - 4 - 300

I am trying to create a loop in jQuery that can provide me the output in an array below:

var groupsArray = [];

```
{
"Rank" : 1
"Total": 200
"TotalRows": 1
},
{
"Rank" : 2
"Total": 200
"TotalRows": 1
},
{
"Rank" : 3
"Total": 1700
"TotalRows": 4
},
{
"Rank" : 4
"Total": 400
"TotalRows": 2
}
```

I am trying this since last two days but unable to find any way to achieve this. I tried with for loop but ended with multiple for loops (one inside other) which is impacting the performance:

```
for(var i=0; i<ds.data.length(); i++)
{
   for(var j=0; j<ds.data.length(); j++)
   {
      if(ds.data(j).GridCell.Rank == i)
      {
           //Create or edit array
      }
   }
   //Add the values to groupsArray
}
```

I also tried using "each" function but couldn't find the correct way to implement the logic above.

Requesting all experts to please help in achieving the above in jQuery with minimum number of loops and increased performance.

Comment: please add the data in literal notation.

Comment: although not optimal, your solution is unlikely to be impact. what happens inside `//Create or edit array` and how large the data is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use simple for loop for this. Hope this helps you !

```
 var data = [{ group: 'A', rank: 1, value: 200 }, { group: 'B', rank: 2, value: 200 }, { group: 'C', rank: 3, value: 200 }, { group: 'D', rank: 3, value: 500 }, { group: 'E', rank: 3, value: 600 }, { group: 'F', rank: 3, value: 400 }, { group: 'G', rank: 4, value: 100 }, { group: 'H', rank: 4, value: 300 }];
    var result = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let row = data[i];
        if(!result.hasOwnProperty(row.rank)) {
            result[row.rank] =  { rank: row.rank, total: 0, totalRows: 0 };
        }
         result[row.rank].total += row.value;
         result[row.rank].totalRows++;
    };
    Object.values(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object as hash table for `rank` and add the parts to the specific rank and get an array of values from the object as result.

```js
var data = [{ group: 'A', rank: 1, value: 200 }, { group: 'B', rank: 2, value: 200 }, { group: 'C', rank: 3, value: 200 }, { group: 'D', rank: 3, value: 500 }, { group: 'E', rank: 3, value: 600 }, { group: 'F', rank: 3, value: 400 }, { group: 'G', rank: 4, value: 100 }, { group: 'H', rank: 4, value: 300 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { rank, value }) => {
        r[rank] = r[rank] || { rank, total: 0, totalRows: 0 };
        r[rank].total += value;
        r[rank].totalRows++;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried this but encountered an error about reduce method. System says "reduce is not a function". I think something related to Kendo dataset that triggers this error.